# Distance between vectors in $R^{21}$ given their dot product

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, vectors

Given vectors $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^{21}$ such that $x\cdot x=10$, $x\cdot y=1$ and $y\cdot y=3$.
 The goal is to find $\|(2x-3y)\|$.

I suppose it is $2{\sqrt{10}} - 3{\sqrt3}$.  Can someone clarify this please, I've tried looking in several textbooks, but can't find the concept behind it.

Comment: $\|v\|=\sqrt{v\cdot v}$. Expand the expression in the norm you’re trying to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||ax-by||=\sqrt{\langle ax-by,ax-by\rangle}=\sqrt{a^2\langle x,x\rangle-2ab\langle x,y\rangle+b^2\langle y,y\rangle}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for two vectors $v,w$,
$$\|v+w\| = \sqrt{\langle v+w, v+w\rangle} = \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle + 2\langle v,w\rangle + \langle w, w\rangle}.$$

Can you apply this fact to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\left\|2x-3y\right\|^2=\left(2x-3y\right)\cdot\left(2x-3y\right)$$